# How can i remove this spacing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website using bootstrap, After the navigation there is a gap going into the content area, Is there a way i can remove it?

Can see in the photo where the red line is, I want to move that up and remove the padding/margin.

[image]

Here is some of the code:

```
<body>

<nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img alt="Logo" class="margin-minus10" src="logo.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/search/"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="/help/"><i class="fa fa-phone-square fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">
<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <div class="slide-1"></div>
      <div class="hero hidden-xs">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Landscaping</h1>        
            <h3>See our portfolio for more work</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">View Portfolio</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-2"></div>
      <div class="hero hidden-xs">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Driveways</h1>        
            <h3>Professionally Laid Driveways</h3>
        </hgroup>       
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">View Driveways</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-3"></div>
      <div class="hero hidden-xs">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Free Quote</h1>        
            <h3>Request a quote with zero obligations</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Contact Us</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .navbar {
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      border: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-bottom:0
    }
    .navbar-default .badge {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #4e5d6c;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .badge {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #df691a;
    }
```

Can see the full code here: http://olli460.com/oak/index.html

Comment: You need to post your CSS as well

Comment: I put a link to the full code, Do i still need to post full css?

Comment: Yes, your question should contain a [mcve]. If you link to the example code and the page is fixed or inaccessible, then your question loses all value to future visitors.

Comment: ok thanks, only reason i didn't was because it's part of the bootstrap css and that file is massive should i put the full css?

Comment: Only post the smallest amount of relevant code. See [mcve]

Comment: If i knew what part was relevant i probably wouldn't of needed to ask the question though. Seeing as i got the answer already i've updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Narrowing down the problem by creating a minimal example often helps locate the issue without the need to open a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file. Place it below the bootstrap css file.

```
.navbar {margin-bottom:0}
```

Answer (score 2):

in css,

```
.navbar{
  margin: 0;  // or margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

this will remove the space.

Comment: either margin-bottom or margin set to 0. Is it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.overlay {
      margin-top: -50px;}
```

This should remove the space between the navbar and overlay div.